# Receiving a 405 HTTP Response from Web API when posting an array of objects (.Net Core 5)

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, webapi, .net-5

I have a .Net Core 5 console app running on Linux (Debian 10) on an Orange Pi.
I am trying to post some JSON to a Web API (also written in .Net Core 5 and hosted on Azure App Service)
The API has two HTTPPOST endpoints - one to receive a single object, and a near identical one to receive an array of said object.

When I post a single object to the first endpoint, I receive a 201 Created status code response. But when I post an array of same object, the API returns a 405 response:

> StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1,
> Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: {
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   Request-Context: appId=   X-Powered-By:
> ASP.NET   Set-Cookie:
> ARRAffinity=10f4677b6e2472959a213314a4f212e32905ecb3d38e1a47aefbb00645a0d541;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=eball-api.azurewebsites.net
> Set-Cookie:
> ARRAffinitySameSite=10f4677b6e2472959a213314a4f212e32905ecb3d38e1a47aefbb00645a0d541;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=eball-api.azurewebsites.net
> Date: Sun, 28 Feb 2021 18:58:41 GMT   Content-Length: 175
> Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 }

This is what my console app looks like:

```
public partial class ReadingDto
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeReceived { get; set; }
    public double? Frequency { get; set; }
    public byte? FrequencyByte { get; set; }
    public byte? Modulation { get; set; }
    public byte? AGC1 { get; set; }
    public byte? AGC2 { get; set; }
    public string RawData { get; set; }
    public bool? IsTest { get; set; }
    public bool IsReported { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeReported { get; set; }
}

private async Task PostReadings(List<ReadingDto> readingsDto)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = "https://somedomain.com/api/";
        string serializedObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(readingsDto);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject);
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("readings/batch", content))
        {
            Console.Write(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what the action method looks like in the API's controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReadingsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("batch")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostReadings([FromBody] List<ReadingDto> readingsDto)
    {
        List<Reading> readings = _mapper.Map<List<Reading>>(readingsDto);
        _context.Readings.AddRange(readings);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Created("GetReadings", readings);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I've searched many forums, and MOST suggest replacing this line:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject);
```

with this

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

But When I do this, I get this error instead:

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: {
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> Request-Context: appId=   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Set-Cookie:
> ARRAffinity=10f4677b6e2472959a213314a4f212e32905ecb3d38e1a47aefbb00645a0d541;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=eball-api.azurewebsites.net
> Set-Cookie:
> ARRAffinitySameSite=10f4677b6e2472959a213314a4f212e32905ecb3d38e1a47aefbb00645a0d541;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=eball-api.azurewebsites.net
> Date: Sun, 28 Feb 2021 19:07:45 GMT   Content-Type:
> application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 }

Comment: Can you add how are you structuring the json array in body

Comment: you would need to send as byte content, have a look at this example https://www.paddingleft.com/2018/04/11/HttpClient-PostAsync-GetAsync-Example/

Comment: Did you all use `ReadingCreateDto` when sending the request? But why did you provide the `ReadingDto`. I suspect that the wrong property leading this error.

Comment: @Karney. Sorry about that - that was a copy-and-paste mistake when creating this post - I have corrected it.

Comment: After adding `Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"`, I have no error. Whether it is caused by violation of data constraints.

Comment: You should add logging to the API that is receiving the posted request, so that you can troubleshoot this - since you are using Azure, Application Insights would be simplest. As it stands now, this question is essentially asking us to debug your code for you, which is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks for the reply Ian. Yes, that is a good suggestion. Unfortunately, i have not been able to work on this all week but tonight I will get a chance. Regarding your comment, that is debatable in my opinion. It's certainly not my expectation for anyone to debug my code. But it's entirely possible that I am making a silly mistake, which someone could've spotted immediately and answered in a few seconds. Believe me I spent two full evenings, working till 1am both nights, before I even thought of posting the question on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem. There was a slight difference between the ReadingDto class used by the client and the ReadingDto class used by the API. The data type for the client version is a nullable integer, whereas the API version is a non-nullable integer. So the client was trying to POST a null in the Id field, which the API didn't like.

I apologize for having wasted everyone's time. Unfortunately I cannot work on this project during office hours as I'm at my job then, so I have to work on it after hours (and then only after my son falls asleep (around 10pm))! That's the problem with working late and tired!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the `StringContent` altogether by using `PostAsJsonAsync` which is included in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` package:

```
await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("url", readingsDto);
```

Also, I would suggest using `IHttpClientFactory` to create the `HttpClient`.

Comment: You need to mention that is not part of the HttpClient class... That is part of the Formatting extensions